# Rails 3 - using cache for form view helpers grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a recurrent view in a form in which the data for the select tags doesn't change very often but it is expensive, so I want to implement cache, it works with some selects but don't know how to make it work with grouped_collection_select.

This is the code I want to cache (sorry about the spanish inflections):

Models code:

```
def self.cached_campuses
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, "campuses"]) do
    Campus.active.order(:name)
  end
end

def self.cached_programas
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, "programas"]) do
    Programa.considered.active.order(:name).map{ |programa| [programa.name, programa.id, {'data-campus'=>programa.campus.id, 'data-nivel'=>programa.nivel.clave}] }
  end
end
#there are more but of the same style
```

Controller:

```
@campus = Campus.cached_campuses
@programas = Programa.cached_programas
# some others
```

View:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  # This reads from cache everything
  = f.input :campus_id, collection: @campus, ...

  # This one doesn't read all from cache, makes queries to the table Nivel cause the grouped_collection
  = f.grouped_collection_select :nivel_id, @campus, :niveles, ...

  # This reads from cache everything
  = f.select :programa_id, options_for_select( @programas )
  # some other selects
```

I need the select with grouped_collection because in the View it is filtered via javascript depending on which option an user selected in the top select.

How can I cache inside the model Nivel the data for the grouped_collection_select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it,

Instead of grouped_collection_select, in a Helper I did:

```
def cached_niveles
  unless Rails.cache.exist?( "select_niveles" )
    Rails.cache.write( "select_niveles", option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Campus.cached_campuses, :niveles, :id, :clave, :nombre) )
  end

  Rails.cache.read( "select_niveles")
end
```

And the form:

```
= select_tag 'usuario[nivel_id]', cached_niveles, prompt: "NIVEL DE INTERÉS"
```

The trick was to use option_groups_from_collection_for_select